# Calculus: function satisfies limit conditions

Tags: calculus, limits

In this Calculus question we need to find the equation of a function $f(x)$ that satisfies these 2 properties based on limits:

> 1) for all $b > 1$, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^b} = 0$
>
> 2) for all $b \leq 1$, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^b} = \infty$

Initially, i did not think it was too bad, but then when I tried out functions, elementary functions, I had difficulties.

I am thinking that its probably an exponential type of function.
I was thinking possibly the gaussian function, but i think it fails the second condition.
Another function is possibly root i think, but not fully certain.
That is all i could think up of, hit a brick wall with this one.

Comment: $f(x) = x\ln x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want $f(x)$ grows "little bit" faster than $x$. So you can make $x$ a coefficient that grows slower than all $x^a$. That's "little bit". For example, how about $\log x$? Put $f(x) = x\log x$ in and test it.

Comment: OK, thanks Monkey King and DougM, I will try this out, and get back on this.

Comment: OK, I tried log(x) which failed, then xlog(x) which worked, and decided to try root function which fails when b=1. So I chose yours as the answer MonkeyKing. Thanks again.

Comment: @Palu Not intended to confuse you, but what I want to say is that you want to multiply $x$ (because $b=1$ is the critical point so you should start with identity function) by something negligible to $x^a$ but grows to $\infty$. It will "fix" the problem that $\lim f(x)/x=N$. So $\log x$ is a good candidate and you should multiply $x$ by it. Root is clearly not a good candidate since $\sqrt[c]{x}=x^{1/c}$, cannot be "cancelled" by denominator when $b$ is close to $1$.

Comment: Hi MonkeyKing, I believe I understood what you meant here. And yes, I was thinking in terms of b=1 because it is like a special edge case. Thanks for adding more details here.